# Drupal view field

Tags: 7, views, entities, users

In Drupal, I would like to display some user related nodes on their "My Account" page. I would like to do so by creating a View that i would add as a field on the user entity (through admin/config/people/accounts/display). I could use Computed Field in order to load and render the view but that is not very convenient as it requires me to write PHP code.

In short, is there a module that allows to add dummy fields containing a view in the "manage display" sections of entities?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is exactly such a module [ViewField](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield).

> Viewfield provides a field that holds a reference to a View and
>   renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.
>
> Features
>   Author chooses a view and display from a list. View arguments
>   are supplied through tokens. Administrators may restrict which views
>   may be assigned. Administrators may supply a common value that will be
>   used for all entities in a content type.

Comment: I tried this module and it adds a field during the entity creation/edition. Is there a way to avoid that (always use default view&arguments) ? Thx btw :-)

Comment: Nevermind I just found the option :-)